# Assign ID to a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a div which already has a class of "testimonial" and I need to dynamically add an ID of "testimonial" too.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
console.log('running');
        $(.testimonial).attr('id', 'testimonial');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

However I am unable to select the element with class of `testimonial` as it will now allow me to include a `.` to notify it is a classname. I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

How else can this be done?

Comment: `$(.testimonial)` -> `$('.testimonial')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  `$('.testimonial').attr('id', 'testimonial');` instead of `$(.testimonial).attr('id', 'testimonial');`

Read more about jquery selectors in here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

Comment: Of all the reference you could find, you've posted the one from w3schools - [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this  `$('.testimonial')` instead of this `$(.testimonial)`